# How to return to previous popup?

Tags: popup, abap, dynpro

I am opening a Popup(1) - Screen_0300

```
CASE sy-ucomm.
  WHEN 'POPUP1'.
    CALL SCREEN 0300 STARTING AT 10 08 ENDING AT 70 15.
ENDCASE.
```

From within this Popup I am calling another screen Popup(2) - Screen_0400.

```
MODULE user_command_0300 INPUT.
  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'POPUP2'.
      CALL SCREEN 0400 STARTING AT 10 08 ENDING AT 70 15.
  ENDCASE.
ENDMODULE.
```

Now when I close Popup(2) I want to return to Popup(1). Currently both Popups get closed simultaneously. I already tried to call Popup(1) in the PAI of Popup(2) with `Leave to Screen` or `Set Screen`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To leave a screen displayed using `CALL SCREEN`, use [`SET SCREEN 0`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapset_screen.htm) during the execution of the PAI (`MODULE ... INPUT`), and the program will continue after the statement `CALL SCREEN`.

`0` is a special value to leave the current "Screen Call Sequence".

Comment: Sadly this closes both popups, but I want to return to the first popup.

Comment: It's due to your code. It's leaving both because you execute `set screen 0` once per screen. Please debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself, posting it so others might find the answer faster. It seems to be the same issues as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024123/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-nested-pop-up-window-in-sap-abap-and-go-back-to-the-pr).

Fixed it with the following:

```
data next_screen type sy-dynnr.
CASE sy-ucomm.
 WHEN 'POPUP1'.
  next_screen = '0300'.
  while next_screen is not INITIAL.
  CALL SCREEN next_screen STARTING AT 10 08 ENDING AT 70 15.
  endwhile.
ENDCASE.
```

And in the second popup:

```
MODULE user_command_0300 INPUT.
  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'CANCEL' OR 'ENTER'
      CLEAR next_screen.
    WHEN 'POPUP2'.
      CALL SCREEN 0400 STARTING AT 10 08 ENDING AT 70 15.
  ENDCASE.
ENDMODULE.
```

This way whenever the first Popup is closed with the sy-ucomm `CANCEL` or `EXIT` next_screen is cleared and the main program is in focus again. Otherwise next_screen keeps being 300 and will be called all the time.